# Xamarin Refit - Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException

Tags: json, xamarin, refit

I have some problems with JSON Serialization.
When I try to deserialize my JSON Object, it returns me this error :

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'Project.Models.BookModel' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.

My problem here is that I have to deserialize my object in two different ways : In a JSON array(e.g.[1,2,3]) to extract "_id", "user" and "name", and then in a JSON array(e.g.["name":"value"]) to extract "books". And I don't know how to do it. Or more precisely, I don't know if it's posible with Refit.

Here is my JSON :

```
[
{
    "_id": "5c014a1e43b6804ed7b642b2",
    "__v": 0,
    "user": "5c014a1d43b6804ed7b642b1",
    "name": "Favoris",
    "books": [
        {
            "_id": "5a8f12e16a16fa06d1f5b0cb",
            "title": "Harry Potter et la Chambre des Secrets",
            "author": {
                "_id": "5a8f12e16a16fa06d1f5b0bd",
                "name": "J K Rowling",
                "__v": 0
            },
            "literaryGenre": "Juvenile Fiction",
            "isbn": 9781781101049,
            "externalImage": "...",
            "__v": 0,
            "content": {
                "brief": "test1"
            }
        },
        {
            "_id": "5a8f12e16a16fa06d1f5b0d0",
            "title": "Harry Potter et la Coupe de Feu",
            "author": {
                "_id": "5a8f12e16a16fa06d1f5b0bd",
                "name": "J K Rowling",
                "__v": 0
            },
            "literaryGenre": "Juvenile Fiction",
            "isbn": 9781781101063,
            "externalImage": "...",
            "__v": 0,
            "content": {
                "brief": "test2"
            }
        }
    ]
}
]
```

Here is my code :

```
public async void ViewLibrary()
    {
        IProjectApi response = ProjectRepository.Instance.ProjectApi;
        List<LibraryModel> library = await response.GetLibrary("5c014a1d43b6804ed7b642b1");

        this.LibraryItems = library;
    }
```

And my object LibraryModel :

```
public class LibraryModel
{
    public string _id { get; set; }

    public string user { get; set; }

    public string name { get; set; }

    public BookModel books { get; set; }
}
```

And my method GetLibrary :

```
    [Get("/api/library/user/{UserId}")]
Task<List<LibraryModel>> GetLibrary(string UserId);
```

Comment: In `LibraryModel` try using `public List<BookModel> books { get; set; }`.

Comment: It works!! Thank you very much! ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type
>   'Project.Models.BookModel' because the type requires a JSON object
>   (e.g. {"name":"value"})

In  `json` result your `BookModel` returning multiple records, so it should be defined as `List<BookModel>`.

In `LibraryModel` try using public `List<BookModel> books { get; set; }`.

Answer (score 0):

Implement these classes anywhere in your code and try to deserialize your json with these classes.

```
public class Author
{
    public string _id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int __v { get; set; }
}

public class Content
{
    public string brief { get; set; }
}

public class Book
{
    public string _id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public Author author { get; set; }
    public string literaryGenre { get; set; }
    public object isbn { get; set; }
    public string externalImage { get; set; }
    public int __v { get; set; }
    public Content content { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string _id { get; set; }
    public int __v { get; set; }
    public string user { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<Book> books { get; set; }
}
```